# Drawing Block diagram of Transfer Function with multi input variables

Tags: transfer-function

I was solving a Transfer function problem with multiple input variables. I decided to draw a simplified block diagram of the function but I cannot find any resources that point me to this specific situation.

input variables y and k, output variable t

y" - 5k = t

Laplace Transform would indicate 2 transform functions G1 and G2 assuming zero initial conditions.

s<sup>2</sup> Y - 5s K = T

G1 = Y/T = 1/s<sup>2</sup>

G2 = K/T = -1/5s

Due to the function having two input variables, would the block diagram result in having two blocks that join together in parallel?

Meaning Transfer function of the above equation is... G = G1 + G2 = 5-s / 5s<sup>2</sup>

Is my reasoning sound? if not, could anyone point me to resources that do?

Comment: Mostly the state space models are built from the fist formula

Comment: `G1` and `G2` are not in parallel since their inputs are not the same signal. Also, is the first equation `y'' - 5k` or `y'' - 5k'` ? Also, if `t` is the output variable, why is the transfer function `Y/T` instead of `T/Y` ?